# Using Hibernate in OSGi without defining packages/classes to scan property

Tags: hibernate, osgi, hibernate-mapping, spring-orm

I have the following situation :

```
Project A - Contains a DB-Configurations and Creates Session_Factory at Init.
Project B - Contains entities and using Project A to persist entities.
Project C - Contains entities and using Project A to persist entities.
```

I am working in OSGi based environment using karaf. I am making small components/Bundles which are using Project A to persist their entities. Project A will be loaded first always as others are dependent on it.

Project A will initiate Session Factory at start but without any packages/classes to scan for entities.

Now any package tries to persist the object using Project A will ended up in exception which is obvious

**org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:**

Is there any way i can persist the entities without scanning any packages/classes...?

Answer (score 1):

SessionFactory has to know about an entity before persisting. In your case, if you register some classes from B and C to A, SessionFactory would probably store some references to these classes, thus breaking modularity.

My suggestion for you would be:

1. Project A: creates java.sql.DataSource and exports it as an osgi service.
2. Projects B and C: import java.sql.DataSource and both create their own SessionFactory, DAO layer and Service layer, and export service layer as osgi services.

Comment: I am doing the same as you have mentioned but the only difference is that Project A is exposing datasource as Service. Project B and C are using that service and sending it to Dao class of Project A to create Session factory from that datasource. We want to create only one Session Factory only that can persist all the entities from all projects.  Bundle of Thanks for your reply. Please do reply if you have any solution for this.

Comment: What is the reason for having "only one Session Factory"?

Comment: Basically we are developing the use-cases in small bundles. It can be possible that 50 use cases will end up in 50 bundles[In OSGi(karaf)]. Now if 30 out of 50 bundles are using database then we will be having 30 Independent connection factories. I don't know how much but it will be consuming resources. That's the reason why we want to have a single Connection Factory.

Comment: Session factory is not for creating "connections" though is not a "connection factory". It just stores some configuration and JPA metadata, and I don't see a reason why it would be "consuming resources". In your case connections are retrieved from datasource, which is singleton, and exposed via OSGi.

Comment: You are right about singleton data-source. But we are using that singleton data-source for creating connection factories. And using Hibernate Session and Transaction. Now problem is that 30 bundles are using that singleton data-source for creating 30 session factories. which we think is not right thing. As we are not sure that how many bundles we will be having in future.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn't play well with OSGi. See the caveats at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch17.html#d5e5021

EclipseLink supports OSGi via the Gemini project, but that has similar limitations:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation/Limitations

Apache Aries JPA allows you to create a PersistenceUnit per Bundle via a Meta-Persistence header in the manifest: http://aries.apache.org/modules/jpaproject.html. This could allow you to share the persistence.xml in project A between bundles B and C, but that still creates two different PersistenceUnits/SessionFactories, I guess.